# sonarqube 4.2 and lombok

Tags: java, sonarqube, lombok

After upgrading SonarQube from 4.0 to 4.2, I got a bunch of 'Unused private fields should be removed' errors from the classes with Lombok annotations.

I have

```
@SuppressWarnings("PMD.UnusedPrivateField")
```

declared at the beginning of all those classes. It worked fine when I was using SonarQube 3.7 and 4.0.

I use

```
mvn sonar:sonar
```

to generate the SonarQube report.

And this shows how my class look like:

```
@Data
@SuppressWarnings("PMD.UnusedPrivateField")
public class MyClass {
    private String field;
}
```

How can I get rid of those errors in version 4.2? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'Unused private fields should be removed' is the message generated by the internal SonarQube rule `squid:S1068`, whereas your `@SuppressWarnings` annotation disables the matching (and deprecated) PMD check.

You might want to check your quality profile, eventually disable this rule, or put some exclusions for the Lombok augmented classes.

Comment: To be more precise, by "putting exclusions for Lombok", I meant that you can set a [rule exclusion](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Narrowing+the+Focus#NarrowingtheFocus-IgnoreIssues) for those classes, so that the rule is disabled only for the concerned code (without even modifying the source code).

Comment: Thanks. That works for me. I ended up putting a rule something like Rule key pattern: squid:S1068, File Path Pattern: **/beans/*.java in 'Ignore Issues on Multiple Criteria' section. Now I also can remove @SuppressWarning from my classes.

Answer (score 1):

You can also individually exclude Sonar analysis on the fields using `//NOSONAR` as well which is nice cause you don't have to disable this rule globally if your @Data classes are scattered around your project, but this option also has the downside that it disables all Sonar analysis on this specific line.

```
@Data
public class MyClass {
    private String field; //NOSONAR
}
```