# SonarQube + Lombok configuration

Tags: sonarqube, lombok

I am starting a new project and I need to Use `SonarQube`, and I want to use `Lombok`, I already configured it within Eclipse and everything works fine except the static analysis.

- Unusued private fields: When I have a `@Data` class, all the fields are reported as `Unused private field`.
- `@Getter(lazy=true)`: When I use this annotation I get the `Redundant nullcheck of value known to be non-null`  see [@Getter(lazy=true)](http://projectlombok.org/features/GetterLazy.html) (this is related to compiled code).

I think a possible solution is `delombok` the project, compile and run Sonar.

Similar issues in `SonarQube Jira`:

- [[CodeGen - Lombok] false warning hint (Unused Private Field)](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-2720)
- [Provide a new java rule to check for unused private field and which would support bytecode generation (cd Lombok)](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONARJAVA-73)
- [[CodeGen - Lombok] false warning hint](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-2718)

(The `@SuppressWarnings("PMD.UnusedPrivateField")` solution don't work with latest `SonarQube 4.2` )

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 7):

As a workaround, I'm now letting sonar do the analysis over the code that delombok generates.

I guess this is also not a perfect solution, because I'm analyzing generated code instead of code that is actually written by a developer. I find it's a better solution though than using `@SuppressWarnings, //NOSONAR` or switching off rules in Sonar itself.

See below an example to achieve this in Maven. Add this to your pom.xml:

```xml
<properties>
    ...
    <!-- This is exposed as a workaround to do the sonar analysis in combination with delombok -->
    <src.dir>src/main/java</src.dir>
    ...
</properties>
...
<plugins>
    ...
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${lombok-plugin.version}</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>verify</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>delombok</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <addOutputDirectory>false</addOutputDirectory>
                    <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
    ...
</plugins>
...
<profiles>
...
<profile>
        <!-- we have to use this profile to analyse code with sonar until https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MSONAR-70 is fixed ! -->
        <id>sonar</id>
        <properties>
            <src.dir>target/generated-sources/delombok</src.dir>
        </properties>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lombok-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${lombok-plugin.version}</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>verify</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>delombok</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <addOutputDirectory>true</addOutputDirectory>
                                <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.2</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
    ...
</profiles>
```

Comment: I added a maven example above in my answer. I tried to put only the relevant parts of the pom so if you have further questions please feel free to ask.

Also I noticed that in the meantime https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MSONAR-70 is fixed, so probably the above code can somehow be simplified.

Comment: Won't this cause problems with SCM plugin/blame?

Answer (score 4):

I have add a [pull request to support more annotation from Lombok](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-java/pull/102).
For the binary, please visit here:

- [SonarQube 4.5.X (or ships sonar-java-plugin-2.4.jar)](https://github.com/liudongmiao/sonar-java/releases/tag/2.4-lombok)
- [SonarQube 5.0.X (or ships sonar-java-plugin-2.8.jar)](https://github.com/liudongmiao/sonar-java/releases/tag/2.8-lombok)

Answer (score 2):

I asked a similar question some time ago:
[sonarqube 4.2 and lombok](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22942608/sonarqube-4-2-and-lombok)

Basically, you can't do it with annotation (like @SuppressWarnings) in the code anymore. Instead, you need to set up a (global) rule exclusion in SonarQube:

Click on Settings -> Exclusions -> Issues
and adding entries in 'Ignore Issues on Multiple Criteria' section, and enter something like:

```
Rule Key Pattern  File Path Pattern
squid:S1068       **/models/**/*.java
```

It makes your source code a little bit cleaner (since you don't need @SuppressWarnings anymore), but I don't like the idea of setting global rules, as it may cause other problems.

---

Update:

For 'Redundant nullcheck of value known to be non-null', you can add something like following:

```
Rule Key Pattern                                   File Path Pattern
findbugs:RCN_REDUNDANT_NULLCHECK_OF_NONNULL_VALUE  **/xxxxx.java
```

And another one that may (or may not) be useful for you:

```
Rule Key Pattern                        File Path Pattern
common-java:InsufficientBranchCoverage  **/models/**/*.java
```

Comment: Yes, I upvoted your question, but your solution only works for the `@Data` annotation, and I have some `@ManagedBeans (JSF)` classes with `@Getter @Setter`, and not all projects use `lombock`, and not all fields uses the annotations, so, I think, in my case, this is not a solution. And with the `@Getter(lazy=true)` this solution don't apply.

Comment: In my project, I have settings to cover 'Redundant nullcheck' warning too. You just need to find those rule keys and add exception to them. (also see my update above)

Comment: I think `lombok` should increase the legibility and reduce the size of code, not forces to disable sonar rules that may be useful for some cases.

Comment: @AVolpe: I'd bet, Lombok does it just right and Sonar is wrong. **1.** With `@Data`, the fields are indeed unused until Lombok generates the getters. It doesn't matter *how* it does it, the problem is with the checking tool not taking the generation into account. **2.** Concerning "Redundant nullcheck of value known to be non-null", the problem is that the value is not *guaranteed* to be non-null, [details](http://code.google.com/p/projectlombok/issues/detail?id=681).

Comment: @maaartinus the `Redundant nullcheck` don't appear when uses in conjuntion with `@Data`, it's appear in a class without the `@Data`. And you're rigth, it's not a lombok problem, it's a SonarQube issue, I don't blame lombok for this problem, I only say that is necessary another solution that don't force the reduce the rule set, for example, when you mark a method with `@PostConstruct` and make it private, Sonar will throw the unused rule, I think we need to define a mechanism to skil some method/fields with a specific annotation.

Comment: @AVolpe I see. I misunderstood your comment (as if you were requesting Lombok doing things differently). I've never tried Sonar, but I'm having similar problems with FindBugs; surprisingly, no single wrong message because of Lombok, but quite a few because of using Gson (which reads and write fields via reflection).

Comment: @AVolpe Would it help, if Lombok added e.g. `@lombok.LombokGenerated` to all the stuff it generates? Could you then define a specific rule?

Answer (score 0):

for multi-modules projects, building on what is mentioned in finrod's answer, I had to add below property in my sonar profile to avoid having duplicated violations (Sonar was analysing both src/main/java and target/generated-sources/delombok)

```
<properties>

    <!-- Sonar will analyze the delombokized version of the code -->
    <sonar.exclusions>src/main/java/**/*</sonar.exclusions>

</properties>
```